# CurrentApp.LicenseInformation.ProductLicenses is loosing information after application update

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, in-app-purchase

I have a durable product. It purchasing correct and handling with CurrentApp.LicenseInformation.ProductLicenses too. But after application update system "loses" information about purchases.
I may call CurrentApp.RequestProductPurchaseAsync() again and user will just accept the message that the product was bought. But this is quite inconvenience. Is there a way to restore in-app purchases after update (beside saving this information into settings)?